# HTTP-заголовок Content-Disposition, имя файла по-русски

Tags: java, http

У меня есть сервлет, который отдаёт файл. Я хочу сделать имя файла по-русски. Строку беру из `ResourceBundle`.

В результате имя в заголовке получается примерно такое:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="K3@C7:0 A?8A:0 >1@0I5=89 02.07.2012.xls"
```

Как мне сделать корректное имя файла на русском? Это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 1):

В формате mhtml подсмотрел такой вариант:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename*0*=utf-8''%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0; filename*1*=%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA %D0%B8.png
Content-Type: image/png; name*0*=utf-8''%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0; name*1*=%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D 0%B8.png
```

Попробуйте так сделать, но соответственно не inline будет.
А потом нашел вот этот [RFC5987](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc5987.html), в котором Вы найдете полную информацию по теме.

Comment: Сделал вот этим способом: http://vova-sukhov.livejournal.com/1488.html Вроде получилось.

Comment: Я про это же и написал :)  Ваш пример единственно отличается, что локаль конкретная указывается `ru-ru`. Не думаю, что сильно критично ее не указать.

Comment: Почему-то способ срабатывает только в FireFox. IE и Chrome игнорируют русское имя и загружают файл по виртуальному имени (названию сервлета).
Пробовал вариацию filename*0*=utf-8 и filename*=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Вот гарантированно работающий код: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/1ccfcdfc11da19a88f6efc6f512e67b68fa04fec/src/System.Web.Mvc/FileResult.cs#L75

Одна проблема - он на C#.

Answer (score -1):

```
MimeUtility.encodeWord(fileName, "utf-8", "Q")
```